# Query list of LiveData objects

Tags: android, mvvm, android-livedata

I want to practice MVVM so I developed a simple Android app using Room,ViewModel and LiveData.
I have two tables, "Users" and "Deals".
The "Deals" table is a table of deals, every deal has an owner which is a user id.
I try to query all the users and their deals at the same time, I managed to query all the users and now I have a LiveData of a List of Users , but I don't know how to query every user and return a List of Pairs  of User and their deals.
Maybe my architecture is wrong or maybe I should embed the deals inside the users table.
What is the best practice to solve this issue?

```
    Transformations.switchMap(ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(UserViewModel::class.java).getAllUsers()){users->
            users.forEach { user->
                ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(DealViewModel::class.java).getUserDeals(user.id).
            return@switchMap ?
    }
```

Comment: Since user and deals are your database tables, you should consider getting the proper data with an SQL-Query instead of building the structure in the UI.

Comment: That's why I did, but I want to show all the users and their deals in a list,and I know how to select them from the databases but how can I combine the results using livedata?

Comment: I meant with a Relation https://developer.android.com/reference/android/arch/persistence/room/Relation

Comment: You should be able to use a single query using JOIN in order to fetch your data, or you can use `@Relation` and `@Embedded` with Room.